# Python regexp to match full or partial word

Tags: python, regex, substring, character-class

Is there a way to get regexp to match as much of a specific word as is possible?  For example, if I am looking for the following words:  yesterday, today, tomorrow

I want the following full words to be extracted:

yest

yesterday

tod

toda

today

tom

tomor

tomorrow

The following whole words should fail to match (basically, spelling mistakes):

yesteray

tomorow

tommorrow

tody

The best I could come up with so far is:

`\b((tod(a(y)?)?)|(tom(o(r(r(o(w)?)?)?)?)?)|(yest(e(r(d(a(y)?)?)?)?)?))\b` [(Example)](http://rubular.com/r/fjizLIs1wN)

Note: I could implement this using a finite state machine but thought it would be a giggle to get regexp to do this.  Unfortunately, anything I come up with is ridiculously complex and I'm hoping that I've just missed something.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so that we can suggest the use cases you'd have missed.

Comment: why isn't `y`, `ye`, `yes` included?

Comment: @HappyCoder - updated.

Comment: @Martin - because "yes" is another word that I might be looking for

Comment: @dkf: Please check my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are looking for should include **optional groups with alternations**.

```
\b(yest(?:e(?:r(?:d(?:ay?)?)?)?)?|tod(?:ay?)?|tom(?:o(?:r(?:r(?:ow?)?)?)?)?)\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kW3yI8/4)

*Note* that **`\b` word boundaries** are very important since you want to match whole words only.

**Regex explanation**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(yest(?:e(?:r(?:d(?:ay?)?)?)?)?|tod(?:ay?)?|tom(?:o(?:r(?:r(?:o(?:w)?)?)?)?)?)` - a capturing group matching

  - `yest(?:e(?:r(?:d(?:ay?)?)?)?)?` - `yest`, `yeste`, `yester`, `yesterd`, `yesterda` or `yesterday`
  - `tod(?:ay?)?` - `tod` or `toda` or `today`
  - `tom(?:o(?:r(?:r(?:o(?:w)?)?)?)?)?` - `tom`, `tomo`, `tomor`, `tomorr`, `tomorro`, or `tomorrow`
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

[See Python demo](http://ideone.com/A5DZq4):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b(yest(?:e(?:r(?:d(?:ay?)?)?)?)?|tod(?:ay?)?|tom(?:o(?:r(?:r(?:ow?)?)?)?)?)\b', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"yest\nyeste\nyester\nyesterd\nyesterda\nyesterday\ntod\ntoda\ntoday\ntom\ntomo\ntomor\ntomorr\ntomorro\ntomorrow\n\nyesteray\ntomorow\ntommorrow\ntody\nyesteday"
print(p.findall(test_str))
# => [u'yest', u'yeste', u'yester', u'yesterd', u'yesterda', u'yesterday', u'tod', u'toda', u'today', u'tom', u'tomo', u'tomor', u'tomorr', u'tomorro', u'tomorrow']
```

Comment: I like your solution for today, very clean.  The solutions for yest(erday) and tom(orrow) are incomplete.  If you look at the one that I came up with, it covers every permutation (minus the case insensitivity) of yest* and tom*; that's what I'm looking for. Sorry, I thought I'd made that clear.

Comment: hmm... looking at your syntax, though, i like that the word permutations are using non-capturing groups, which is where mine produces ugly results.  Yours could be expanded to `\b(tom(?:o(?:r(?:r(?:o(?:w)?)?)?)?)?)\b`, for example... 

It's an ugly re but it is cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe separate all the valid words or word substrings like below. This will only match the valid spellings as desired

```
^(?|yest|yesterday|tod|today)\b
```

Tested this already at https://regex101.com/

Comment: This is a PCRE regex. The question is related to Python.

Comment: I see.  There is a nice input on PCRE regex support on python here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940150/how-can-i-use-pcre-regexes-from-a-python-script

Comment: That is not PCRE, **PyPi regex** module is even cooler :) It really is a combination of all the best features from PCRE and .NET regex flavors.