# Django form field accept arabic and english

Tags: regex, django

this is my forms.py

```
regex = re.compile(ur'  range ?? ',  re.UNICODE)

class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    username = forms.RegexField(max_length=50, regex=regex,)
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields =  ('username','email','first_name','last_name','password')
```

if there is a way to allow arabic character in the field

Comment: What about `\p{Arabic}`?

Comment: form validation raise : Enter a valid value. when regex = re.compile(ur'\p{Arabic}',re.UNICODE)

Comment: Take a look at this post: [Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063420/perl-compatible-regular-expression-pcre-in-python) it does a good job of explaining your issue and gives a workaround for python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution:

```
def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        match = re.compile(ur'^[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z]+[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z-_]*$')
        if match.findall(username):
            return username
```

**But:** the validator from django.contrib.auth.models:

```
username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator() if six.PY3 else ASCIIUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
```

stopped me so i delete it :p